# Natbib is displaying author? for citet citations. Need help with Scientific Reports template available on Overleaf

Tags: natbib, wlscirep

Natbib is displaying author? for citet citations. Need help with Scientific Reports template available on Overleaf

```
\documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{wlscirep}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bibfile.bib}
@InProceedings{jeannetmine09, 
   Author = {Jeannet, B. and Min\'e, A.},
   Title = {{APRON}: A Library of Numerical Abstract Domains for Static Analysis},
   BookTitle = {Computer Aided Verification, CAV'2009},
   Volume = {5643},
   Pages = {661--667},
   Series = {LNCS},
   Year = {2009}
} 

\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\cite{jeannetmine09}    % gives [1]

\citet{jeannetmine09}   % gives (author?) [1]

\citep{jeannetmine09}   % gives [1]

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{bibfile}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `wlscirep` document class loads the `cite` citation management package (which is meant to be used with bibliography styles that generate numeric-style citation callouts) and the `naturemag` bibliography style. `naturemag` creates superscript-type numeric citation callouts.

The preamble of your test document contains the instruction `\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}`, but `natbib` and `cite` are mutually incompatible. Moreover, since the `naturemag` bibliography style is loaded automatically by the document class, the `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}` instruction found in the body of the document is simply ignored.

What's surprising, then, isn't that `\citet` isn't working correctly. Rather, it's the fact that `\citep` works at all.

Moral of the story: (a) you should be using only `\cite` instructions when using the `wlscirep` document class; (b) delete (or, at least, comment out) the instructions `\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}` and `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}`.

Comment: So, there is no way to cite author in `wlscirep` class?

Comment: @Y.zeng - Please post a new query.

Comment: Thanks. I have post a new query at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/713629/245010